# на главной странице сайта вылетает

Tags: mysql, веб-программирование

> Notice: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') AND cd1.language_id = '4' AND cd2.language_id = '4' GROUP BY cp.category_id OR' at line 1
>   Error No: 1064

Comment: Ну запрос кривой... ищи, где по коду он формируется, и исправляй.

Comment: @Людмина Спица Добавьте в вопрос сам запрос.