# Ошибка синтаксиса в SQL-запросе на получение данных

Tags: php, mysql

> Notice: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near ') AND cd1.language_id = '4' AND cd2.language_id = '4' GROUP
>   BY cp.category_id OR' at line 1 Error No: 1064 SELECT cp.category_id
>   AS category_id, GROUP_CONCAT(cd1.name ORDER BY cp.level SEPARATOR '  >
>   ') AS name, c1.parent_id, c1.sort_order FROM oc_category_path cp LEFT
>   JOIN oc_category c1 ON (cp.category_id = c1.category_id) LEFT JOIN
>   oc_category c2 ON (cp.path_id = c2.category_id) LEFT JOIN
>   oc_category_description cd1 ON (cp.path_id = cd1.category_id) LEFT
>   JOIN oc_category_description cd2 ON (cp.category_id = cd2.category_id)
>   WHERE c1.parent_id IN () AND cd1.language_id = '4' AND cd2.language_id
>   = '4' GROUP BY cp.category_id ORDER BY sort_order ASC in /home/abvmebel/abvmebel.com.ua/www/system/library/db/mysqli.php on
>   line 41Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   /home/abvmebel/abvmebel.com.ua/www/catalog/model/module/so_listing_tabs.php
>   on line 206Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /home/abvmebel/abvmebel.com.ua/www/catalog/controller/module/so_listing_tabs.php
>   on line 399

Comment: Пользуйтесь кнопкой [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1084856/edit) в [первоначальном вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084856).

Answer (score 3):

Ошибка в этом месте: `WHERE c1.parent_id IN ()`, у вас ничего не подставляется в `IN()`. Подразумевается, что там будет список идентификаторов.

Comment: можно подробнее пожалуйста,что изменить нужно

Comment: Для начала уточните, вы сами составляете этот sql-запрос или он формируется автоматически с помощью какого-то класса?

Comment: как я полагаю он формируется автоматически,честно говоря я не сильно разбираюсь что да как

Comment: Для начала приложите скрипт, в котором осуществляется выборка данных, в вашем вопросе.

Comment: foreach ($categoryss as $category)
    {
     if(!in_array($category['category_id'],$category_arr))
     {
      $category_arr[] = $category['category_id'];
     }
    }
   }
  }
  
  return $category_arr;

Comment: }

  $query = $this->db->query($sql);

  return $query->rows;
 }

Comment: Код нужно выкладывать не в комментариях, а в тексте самого **вопроса**.
И для начала изучите базовые вещи по составлению sql-запросов и основательно разберитесь в коде вашего проекта.